# What are isodiaphers?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, terminology

We know that isodiaphers have same difference in neutrons and protons, but I encountered another definition:

> Atoms which have same isotopic axis are called isodiaphers.

I don't know what it means by "isotopic axis". Please try to explain in simple words.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are basic terms of radiochemistry:

*Isotopes* are nuclides with a common number of protons $Z$.
*Isobars* are nuclides with a common number of nucleons $A$.
*Isotones* are nuclides with a common number of neutrons $N$.
***Isodiaphers*** are nuclides with a common neutron excess $N-Z=A-2Z$.

Thus, in the chart of the nuclides, isodiaphers are found in diagonals from bottom left to top right. For example, the mother and daughter nuclides of alpha decay are isodiaphers.